# UIButton doing different tasks

Tags: swift, uibutton

How do i make a UIButton do something different every time it is pressed in swift. Ive tried making two buttons that overlap and one hides when it is clicked Didn't work though.

EDIT: nevermind i found i could do this for a mute/play button

```
If backgroundaudio.play
```

Backgroundaudio.pause
Else 
Backgroundaudio.play

Comment: You can call whatever other function you like in your IBAction function. Just use some conditions to determine which function to use

Comment: how would i do that can u demonstrate?

Comment: I will post a short answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two different ways:

**Changing the target of the button:**

*Adding a target:*

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

*Removing a target:*

```
button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

**Or have a logical statement inside your action function:**

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!)
{ 
     //your conditions go here
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys really apreatiate

Comment: If they were helpful you should probably accept someone's.

Answer (score 0):

For example: To do something every other time you could write:

```
func oneThing() {
    // Do your stuff
}

func otherThing() {
    // Do other stuff
}

var shouldDoOtherThing = false

@IBAction func clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if shouldDoOtherThing {
        otherThing()
    } else {
        oneThing()
    }
    shouldDoOtherThing = !shouldDoOtherThing
}
```

You could also just do the stuff you want to do inside the if statement like

```
var shouldDoOtherThing = false

@IBAction func clicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if shouldDoOtherThing {
        // Do other stuff
    } else {
        // Do your stuff
    }
    shouldDoOtherThing = !shouldDoOtherThing
}
```

Or you can use anything else that changes what code should execute (they are called Control Statements)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this out. You'll only need one button.You can do as many random things as you want

```
@IBAction func button_click(sender: AnyObject) {

    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(5) + 1) // generates random number 1 - 5

    println(randomNumber)

    switch randomNumber { // perform method depending on what random number was generated

    case 1 :
        funcOne() // Run this method
        println("Pressed 1")

    case 2:
        funcTwo() // Runs this method
        println("Pressed 2")

    case 3:
        funcThree() // Runs this method
        println("Pressed 3")

    case 4:
        funcFour() // Runs this method
        println("Pressed 4")

    case 5:
        funcFive() // Runs this method
        println("Pressed 5")

    default:
        println("do nothing")
    }  
}
```